# How can I use the Nullable Operator with the Null Conditional operator?

Tags: c#, nullable, null-conditional-operator, null-propagation-operator

**Old Way**

```
int? myFavoriteNumber = 42;
int total = 0;
if (myfavoriteNumber.HasValue)
  total += myFavoriteNumber.Value *2;
```

**New way?**

```
int? myFavoriteNumber = 42; 
total += myFavoriteNumber?.Value *2; //fails
```

Comment: What's wrong with `int total = (myfavoriteNumber.HasValue) ? myFavoriteNumber.Value * 2 : 0;`? Still one line, and more readable than your suggested "new way"

Comment: @ShadowWizard I am assuming that he might want to use this function several times hence the use of += so that he can keep a running total? I'm just guessing. I still liked your comment as I agree with you.

Comment: @PrimeByDesign I would go with `??`, as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35970536/111794) answer.

Answer (score 4):

The null-propagation operator ?. will as it says, propagate the null value. In the case of int?.Value this is not possible since the type of Value, int, cannot be null (if it were possible, the operation would become `null * 2`, what would that mean?). So the 'Old Way' is still the current way to do this.

Comment: _what would that mean?_ Just as an aside, usually any number multiplied by NULL returns NULL. That's how normal SQL works, for example. NULL often means "I don't know the value". Imagine this example: I multiply 5 apples for NULL $ per apple. So I _don't know_ the cost of an apple. The consequence is that _I can't know_ the total cost, so the result is NULL.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
int? myFavoriteNumber = 42; 
total += (myFavoriteNumber??0) *2;
```

The expression (`myFavoriteNumber?? 0`) returns 0 in case of `myFavoriteNumber` is null.

Answer (score 3):

I think you misunderstood the use of `null` conditional operator.
It is used to short circuit a chain of *ifs* to `null`, when one of the steps yields `null`.

Like so:

```
userCompanyName = user?.Company?.Name;
```

Please note that `userCompanyName` will contain `null` if `user` or `user.Company` is `null`.
In your example `total` cannot accept `null`, so it's more about the use of ?? than anything else:

```
total = (myFavoriteNumber ?? 0) * 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int? myFavoriteNumber = 42; 
total += (myFavoriteNumber.Value!=null)? myFavoriteNumber.Value*2 : 0;
```